# Is it possible to tell if an variable is an object that was just created with new and get the object type?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

Let's take this code:

```
var charles = new Person();
```

Can I somehow inspect the `charles` variable and see that it was created with the `new` word and also find out that it is of type `Person`?

Comment: Operator `instanceof`

Comment: Depends on what `Person` exactly is. But try `charles.constructor`.

Comment: How does it matter if it was created with new?

Answer (score 0):

an instance is created by using new anyway unless a standard type like string or int etc.

so:

```
function exampleObj(){
    this.exampleAttr=1;
}

var exampleInstance = new exampleObj();

if(exampleInstance instanceof exampleObj){
    alert("i am an example");
}
```

The same applies for reserved types so instanceof String, instanceof int
You always get a boolean.